# How to initialize the ability instance rules when the application starts?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js, casl

I am trying to implement CASL with vuex and Nuxt. I get an issue when trying to initialize ability's rules when my application starts and I am already logged in.

Basically, I would like to get the rules and updates the Ability instance when the app starts. However, when I try to get the rules from the store, it returns `null`. At the moment, I need to log out and log in to get the rules.

store/ability.js

```
import ability from '../config/ability'

export const updateAbilities = store => {
  ability.update(store['users/getRules']) // this does not work and returns null
  return store.subscribe(mutation => {
    if (mutation.type === 'users/setRules') {
      ability.update(mutation.payload)
    }
  })
}
```

config/ability.js

```
import { Ability } from '@casl/ability'

export default new Ability()
```

store/index.js

```
import { updateAbilities } from './ability'

export const plugins = [updateAbilities]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by getting the rule from the Local Storage and it works.

```
import ability from '../config/ability'

export const updateAbilities = store => {
  const vuexData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vuex'))
  const rules = vuexData.users.rules

  ability.update(rules)
  return store.subscribe(mutation => {
    if (mutation.type === 'users/setRules') {
      ability.update(mutation.payload)
    }
  })
}
```